# Sender as TObject for Case ... of with Delphi

Tags: delphi

would like to use a Sender as TObject as a selection criteria for my case ... statement

```
procedure TForm.ShowGUI (Sender: TObject);
begin
  case sender of
      ToolButton1: begin
          do_something;         
        end;

      ToolButton2: begin
          /// 
        end;

      ToolButton3: begin
          do_stufff_here; 
        end;

      ToolButton3: begin 
          /// 
        end;

      else ;

  end;
end;
```

An trick to make the sender an ordinal type as requested by the case statement ?

Comment: A trick would be to create actions to show different GUI types and assign each action to proper buttons

Comment: It's about time Delphi would start being more flexible about the `case` statement. They *could* automatically convert the case statement to a series of `if` statements behind-the-scenes, allowing us to use non-constant expressions and strings. Would save us the manual labor, since we're doing it anyway.

Comment: @Cosmin: pattern-matching in Delphi was discussed year ago in EMBA forums, and Nick Hodges, if my memory serves me, even put this as a posibility for Delphi II language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily convert the `Sender` to an ordinal by converting it to an integer (example: `NativeUInt(Sender)` - but that will do you no good because the `case` statement expects constant expressions for the "branches", and `ToolButton1`..`ToolButton3` aren't constants, they're variables.

You could for example do a case on a property of the buttons; For example, give each `ToolButton` a `Tag` property that's meaningful for it. Then you could do something like this:

```
case (Sender as TToolButton).Tag of
  1: ; // ToolButton1 was pressed
  2: ; // ToolButton2 was pressed        
end;
```

*As suggested by David:* Unless the control you're using has a property that directly relates to it's function (very unlikely), then a simple chained if statement might be easier to read. The `Tag` property as in my first suggestion would need to be specifically configured, and it's just an other way to introduce errors. Example: maybe you copy-paste a button but forget to change it's Tag, you've now got two buttons with the same Tag.

First of all, you should rename all the components you're using from code, give them proper names. Then you could write something like this:

```
if (Sender = tbAlignTextLeft) then
  begin
     // The tool-button for left text alignment was pressed
  end
else if (Sender = tbAlignTextCenter) then
  begin
    // Center-alignment button was pressed
  end
else
  begin
    // This would be the default action. If it were me, I'd raise an exception here.
  end
```

Comment: +1 If you do this I suggest you set up the tags in code, rather than in the object inspector and use constants rather than numbers. This may well make maintenance easier in the future.

Comment: Whilst you could do this, an if statement would be cleaner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Clearly, there could be more than two buttons in which case the `case` is much cleaner.

Comment: @Smasher Only if you pretend that you didn't write magic constants and poke around with `Tag` properties. If you consider the entire picture then the `case` option loses heavily.

Comment: I disagree. If the case contains only single method calls, I find it very easy to read.

Comment: @Smasher Yes, it is very easy to read. That's not my point. Clearly I'm not expressing myself well. The problem I have with that is the fact that you have to somewhere set `Tag` for each control. And somehow relate that to the enumeration in the case statement. Now, if that's done in a .dfm file, how do you like maintaining that?

Comment: Okay, I see your point now. You would have to keep the `case` and the "tagging" in sync. I just thought about readability.

Comment: Or set the tag programmatically in FormCreate or an overridden Create - still a lot of error prone wiring to do to get it right though.

Comment: Can he have hashes for classnames ?
Well, i believe he can setup dictionary or array - lookup-table - to match classes with pre-defined IDs, and then do case over IDs

Answer (score 6):

Consider adding a bit of runtime support to associate an enumeration with your controls.

First create an enumerated type:

```
type
  TControlID = (cidAlignTextLeft, cidAlignTextRight, ....);
```

Then add a dictionary to your form:

```
FControlIDs: TDictionary<TControl, TControlID>;
```

Then in the form's constructor create and populate the dictionary:

```
FControlIDs := TDictionary<TControl, TControlID>.Create;
FControlIDs.Add(tbAlignTextLeft, cidAlignTextLeft);
FControlIDs.Add(tbAlignTextRight, cidAlignTextRight);
....
```

This section of code should be placed in a separate local helper function rather than inline in your form's constructor.

Now you can write your case statement:

```
case FControlIDs[Sender as TControl] of
cidAlignTextLeft:
  ....
cidAlignTextRight:
  ....
```

Comment: You might as well stuff the `TControlID` into the `Tag` and then hard-cast the `Tag` to `TControlID` for the case statement. Just about the same minus the Dictionary lookup.

Comment: @CosminPrund I have a strong loathing of `Tag`. Using it makes me feel dirty. Like I'm coding in VB6. If you forget to assign `Tag` for one of the controls then it defaults to `cidAlignTextLeft`!

Comment: Put a `cidUnassigned` as the first enumeration element to guard against that.

Comment: @CosminPrund Sure you could do that. I like type safety. I don't like `Tag`. I also don't like `Sender: TObject` but there's not a right lot to do about that. At least the `as` cast enforces runtime type safety.